# How to find Google map flight mode android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying shortest path between two locations in android using Google map Api.
My problem is I am getting the routes with different modes (driving, walking, bicycling and transit).
This time I am trying flight mode.
But I don't know which mode should I use to get the route between two airports' locations.

code:

```
 urlString.append( "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" 
             + "origin=" + 17.2400 + "," + 78.4281  
             + "&destination=" + 19.0886 + "," + 72.8681 
             + "&sensor=false"+ "&mode=walking");
```

Which mode should I use for aeroplane way?

Comment: No such mode in Google Map API ...